# Spring is unable to inject an EntityManager using @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have a Java 8/spring 4.3.5.RELEASE web application tha runs on a wildfly 10 server. I use a persistence.xml file. I enabled trace logging on the jboss jpa and hibernate classes and I can see this file gets picked up and is resolved smoothly into a persistence unit:

```
DEBUG [] [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: testcontext
    persistence provider classname: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    classloader: ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.BasicWebapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    excludeUnlistedClasses: false
    JTA datasource: org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource@fb80232
    Non JTA datasource: null
    Transaction type: JTA
    PU root URL: vfs:/C:/Users/Me/Wildfly 10.0.0/standalone/deployments/BasicWebapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/
    Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
    Validation Mode: AUTO
    Jar files URLs []
    Managed classes names [
        com.company.project.data.User]
    Mapping files names []
    Properties [
        jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name: persistence/testcontext]
```

I now want a dao class to have an entity manager injected by spring:

**UserDao.class**

```
@Repository
public class UserDao
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testcontext")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

I have component scanning and annotation config so both the @Repository and the @PersistenceContext annotation gets processed upon starting my application:

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.project" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/testcontext"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

The injection fails though, in two possible ways:

If I use `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "testcontext")`, the error is: 
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'testcontext' available`

If I use `@PersistenceContext`, the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:580)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:707)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 44 more
```

So I'm missing something in this configuration to tell the part of Spring that processes the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to look at either the entityManagerFactory bean that I declared in the spring-servlet.xml or just use the container's persistence unit directly. What do I need to add to achieve that?

I'm also a bit sketchy on the transactionmanager part. Does wildfly provide the transactionmanager or not? If it does, do I need to create a bean for it in Spring (will it pick up the one created by jboss or make its own one?)

Comment: The jndi-name="persistence/**testcontext**" but @PersistenceContext(unitName = "**textcontext**"). Could be just wrong names used there

Comment: Sorry, just a typo in the question. If you look at the UserDao class snippet you will see it was testcontext all along

Comment: Could you include your persistence.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should double check you configuration setup against Spring official docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa-setup-jndi .No, the transaction manager is provided by Spring. More info on this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-strategies